# Select field from a table its name come from an other select

Tags: sql

My second problem is simple to explain, but hard for me to resolve.

I want to Select values from table_Name when this table_Name comes from an other Select

Take this Example:

First Select

```
SELECT
    (SELECT ad_table.tablename
    FROM ad_table
    WHERE ad_table.ad_table_id =fact_acct.ad_table_id
    )
  FROM fact_acct
```

Result = C_Invoice

Second Select

```
 SELECT documentNo
    FROM
      (SELECT
        (SELECT ad_table.tablename
        FROM ad_table
        WHERE ad_table.ad_table_id =fact_acct.ad_table_id
        )
      FROM fact_acct
      )
```

This Select must be The same as: `SELECT documentNo from C_Invoice`

So any ideas?

Comment: Horrible selects... Why those weird constructions?

Comment: dynamic sql!!!!  which rdbms???

Comment: because in the table fact_acct i have record_id (document ID) and table name (Docuùent) "invoice, payment, bankstatements,...ect" , so to get the document name i must do this

Comment: Add a few rows sample table data, and it's expected result!

Comment: Sounds like a bad db design..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Dynamic SQL Query 
try like this

```
DECLARE @TableName NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @TableName = ad_table.tablename
FROM ad_table
WHERE ad_table.ad_table_id =fact_acct.ad_table_id

SET @Sql='SELECT documentNo FROM '+@TableName

EXEC(@Sql)
```

Comment: That's very product specific SQL. (And no dbms is tagged.) At least tell us which dbms it's written for.